# Logging stream filter for PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to debug a socket connection that my PHP frontend makes to a backend service on another host, and I need to do this *as close to the metal as possible*. I 've already abstracted the connection at various levels, which among others gives me the capability to easily attach [stream filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-register.php) to the connection. So the problem should be very easy to solve: package a stream filter into a class which allows arbitrary callbacks to be executed when data is sent or received, and then for example append these to a couple of log files.

The only trouble is that my (naive?) expectation that there should be some such filter implementation floating online appears to be wrong! I don't mind writing the filter myself, but maybe there is something available that I just didn't manage to find?

For reference, I did google many obvious variations on "php logging stream filter".

**Update:** To clarify, what I 'm looking for is something that would allow me to write code morally equivalent to this:

```
$params = array(
    'onDataSent' => function($data) { echo "Sent: $data\n"; },
    'onDataReceived' => function($data) { echo "Received: $data\n"; },
);

stream_filter_register('logging', 'HookableStreamFilter');
stream_filter_append($someStream, 'logging', STREAM_FILTER_ALL, $params);
```

Comment: not sure I understand what you are looking for, but would http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php be an option? This would allow you to hook into certain stream events.

Comment: @Gordon: That wouldn't cut it because I am interested in receiving the actual data from the stream so I can log it. Even if it did, what I 'm looking would be that functionality packed into a class with a sensible API. I 'll make an edit to show example code.

Comment: Do you have the interface definitions of your abstraction available?

Comment: @hakre: Sorry, I 'm not allowed to disseminate that code.

Comment: What about a packet sniffer like wireshark - this would show you the packets, and their contents, being transmitted/sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, here's what I ended whipping up. The filter itself derives from `php_user_filter`, which is described in the docs for [`stream_filter_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-register.php):

```
class HookableFilter extends php_user_filter {
    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        $data = '';

        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            $data .= $bucket->data;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }

        call_user_func($this->params, $data);
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}
```

Note that I 'm using directly `$this->params` as the callback, making this really spartan in function (there's a reason; see below).

Registering the filter with PHP:

```
stream_filter_register('generic.hookable', 'HookableFilter');
```

Attaching the filter to the stream:

```
$callback = function($data) { /* log the data */ };
stream_filter_append($stream, 'generic.hookable', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $callback);
stream_filter_append($stream, 'generic.hookable', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $callback);
```

**Important:** As far as I was able to see, if you attach a filter to both channels of a duplex stream (e.g. one produced with [`stream_socket_client`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)) *there is no way for your filter to know on which channel it's operating when it is invoked*. Therefore if you need to differentiate between incoming and outgoing data as I was, the only option is to attach the filter separately to each channel. If you do, you will also certainly want to supply a different callback for each channel (not the same as done in the simplified example above).